# Building a button to generate a new class each time

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I've built a simple grid-based game but it currently only works for a single game and I want it to work seamlessly for multiple games without needing to refresh the page so I can preserve score data.

When it first loads up I create a variable to instantiate a new 'Game' object

```
const game = new Game();
```

Inside the 'Game' object, there's a method to create a 5x4 sized grid of 20 spaces with the id for each space pulled from an array called 'positions'

```
createBoard() {
      // Clear the board space
      grid.innerHTML = ``;
      // Create new board space
      for (let i=0; i<20; i++) {
        grid.innerHTML += `<div class="box" id="${this.positions[i]}"></div>`;
      }
    }
```

and there's some code to identify when the grid is clicked

```
grid.addEventListener("click", function clickEvent(e) {
    if (game.ready == true) {
        if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
            game.clickGrid(e);
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}, false);
```

For a new game I'd need to update the variable to something like

```
const game2 = new Game();
```

and update that reference in the event listener accordingly.

How can I update the variable and the associated event listener code?

If I was building this game in a traditional, procedural style without explicit classes and methods then I'd probably just create a function to wipe the accumulated data clean and start over but it seems like it should be easier to create a new class, despite the fact that doing it dynamically is proving difficult.

Comment: A need to have mutliple variables most often means you just need an **array**. However, it's not that clear from your question how these mutliple games are related to the click event.

Comment: How exactly do you want to change the event listener when you create a new game?

Comment: My apologies. The grid is generated via a method inside the game object. So a new Game object would create a new grid.

Comment: Could you clarify why you're creating a new game object? If what you want to do is reset the state, it should be easier to do with a method on the existing game (although this is hard to judge without seeing the whole code). On another note, you can preserve game data through page refresh with [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: My reason for creating a new game object was simply that I just assumed it had to  be the simplest way to start a new game. If it's true that it is simpler/recomended to run a method that resets the data I can go that route.

Comment: The only way I know of that would change the instance pointed to by the event listener would be to have a global variable - say `currentGame` which the listener used and you changed when you created the new game. Another thing you could do would be to remove the listener and create a new one. Although, I'm not sure how complicated to implement that would be compared to having a method that clears the state, so it's up to you to decide what you want to do.

Comment: Sounds like that's probably the way to go with this. Thanks for the advice guys.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution but it seems to work.

Instead of instantiating the game object with

```
const game = new Game();
```

I changed it to

```
let game = new Game();
```

which means in my 'New Game' button event handler I can instantiate a new game object by reassigning my game variable with

```
game = new Game();
```

with the advantage that I don't need to update the grid click event handler. I've already inserted the result data from my game into a separate global object meaning I haven't lost anything.